# how to use an integer in a button name for a loop statement

Tags: loops, while-loop

ok i have been searching for 5 days on this now and can not find what i am looking for.

i have 21 buttons on my main form. name structure is btn_Cat1 - btn_cat21
Here is my code so far, but this only does ONE button. i need to do a "do while" or some kind of loop to change the text on each button.

```
Private Sub frm_MainConsole_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

'Procedures

Me.Show()
dbconn()
' Variables

Dim query As String
Dim command As MySqlCommand
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

' creates the button text

Try
    query = "select btn_caption from button_cat"
    command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    reader.Read()
    btn_Cat1.Text = reader("btn_caption")

Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    conn.Close()
    conn.Dispose()
End Try

End Sub
```

What i'm REALLY having an issue with is the button naming in the code. IE:

```
dim i as integer

'this is what i would have done in pascal to advance the button name to the next button:
while i < 21 do
btn_Cat(i).text = "new button text from Database";
i = i+1;
'advance database record to next record
```

Comment: I'm presuming this is VB.Net?

Comment: Sorry yes. Visual basic 2015

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Controls` collection of the form to achieve this - finding each button by it's `Key`.

The example below should give you an idea of how to achieve this:

```
// For button 1 through 21
For i As Integer = 1 To 21 Step 1
    Dim TargetButton As Button

    // Get the button from the controls container
    TargetButton = Controls("btn_Cat" & i)
    TargetButton.Text = reader("btn_caption")
Next
```

You will need to implement the code to get the actual name from the database but this should get you started.

You may wish to use `TryCast` when fetching the control from the `Controls` container and then test to make sure that the button was actually returned.

Comment: Thanks Martin, do you happen to know how to tell the database to advance to the next record? I REALLY APPRECIATE all your help, and not bashing me for being a newbie.